# stuck with stash in git

Tags: git, git-stash

I am using git, but have alot to learn.  I wanted to save some changes to a file (but not commit) and go to a different branch, have a look at some code there then go back to what I was working on.  That's all.  So I did

```
> git stash
> git checkout
> vi ....
> git stash apply stash@{0}
```

and found myself facing an error message

```
Auto-merging schematic.f
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in schematic.f
```

I obviously didn't realize how stash apply was going to work.  And now I'm stuck.  Nothing I can think of doing will get me out of my current branch and back to the one I was working in.  I keep getting this same error message over and over.  How do I get out of this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, `apply` means *try out the stash in my current work-tree, but keep the stash* so the stash itself is fully intact.<sup>1</sup>  And, based on your command sequence (and assuming `vi ...` was just to look at something, not change it), your `stash` then `checkout` should have left you a clean work-tree at the now-current commit, so all you have to do is force the work-tree to match the current commit, with:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

(note that `git reset --hard` wipes away any changes made to the work-tree so be sure that all the changes there are just ones made by `git stash apply`: you might want to check `git status` and `git diff` first, for instance, just to be doubly and triply sure).

Once the work-tree is clean again, you can `git checkout` the branch you *do* want the changes on, `git stash apply` the stash, and if all goes well, `git stash drop` it.

---

<sup>1</sup>I always recommend `git stash apply` instead of `git stash pop` for this reason, although in fact, `pop` only drops the stash if it applies cleanly, so the distinction is pretty small.

Comment: Phew!  That worked!  Thanks.  Will accept your answer in a few minutes when stackoverflow lets me.  In general, if I do a merge, see conflicts, and think "Uh-oh.  I'm not ready for a merge after all," is this the way to back out?  Thanks.

Comment: @bob.sacamento - I would recommend `git merge --abort` in that case. `git reset --hard` can be potentially dangerous, so should be used with great care, so I wouldn't make it a habit to use it casually.

Comment: @DavidDeutsch, @bob.sacamento: agreed, `git merge --abort` is the right way to stop a merge started with `git merge`.  (Other commands, including `git stash apply`, use the merge machinery, but they aren't running "a merge" so there's no merge to abort.)